# Gauss-Jordan Elimination in C++

Tags: c++

I was using Gauss-Jordan elimination in C++ to solve a system of linear equations.
Code works fine. Was wondering why Lines 1,2,3 in `void gauss()` can't be replaced by Line 4 (getting incorrect output after doing so)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Gauss
{
    float a[50][50];
    int n;
public:
    void accept()
    {
        cout<<"Enter no. of variables: ";
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
            {
                if(j==n)
                    cout<<"Constant no."<<i+1<<" = ";
                else
                    cout<<"a["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"] = ";
                cin>>a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"\n";
            for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
            {
                if(j==n)
                    cout<<" ";
                cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
            }
        }
    }

    void gauss()//converting augmented matrix to row echelon form
    {
        float temp;//Line 1
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                temp=a[j][i]/a[i][i];//Line 2
                for(int k=i;k<n+1;k++)
                {
                      a[j][k]-=temp*a[i][k];//Line 3
                    //a[j][k]-=a[j][i]*a[i][k]/a[i][i];//Line 4
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void EnterJordan()//converting to reduced row echelon form
    {
        float temp;
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        {

            for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                temp=a[j][i]/a[i][i];
                for(int k=n;k>=i;k--)
                {
                    a[j][k]-=temp*a[i][k];
                }
            }
        }

        float x[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)//making leading coefficients zero
            x[i]=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
            {
                if(x[i]==0&&j!=n)
                    x[i]=a[i][j];
                if(x[i]!=0)
                    a[i][j]/=x[i];
            }
        }
    }
    void credits()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"\nx"<<i+1<<" = "<<a[i][n]<<endl;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    Gauss obj;
    obj.accept();
    cout<<"\n\nAugmented matrix: \n\n\n";
    obj.display();
    obj.gauss();
    cout<<"\n\nRow Echelon form: \n\n\n";
    obj.display();
    obj.EnterJordan();
    cout<<"\n\nReduced row echelon form:\n\n\n";
    obj.display();
    cout<<"\n\nSolution: \n\n\n";
    obj.credits();
    return 0;
}
```

> Note: My code doesn't take into consideration the problem of division when the pivot is zero (I'm choosing the diagonal element as the pivot every time). 
>   For the particular example I tried however, such a case was not encountered.

Augmented matrix is :

```
 2   1  -1    8 
-3  -1   2   -11    
-2   1   2   -3
```

The output matrix is :

```
1   0   0    2  
0   1   0    3  
0   0   1    -1
```

and the solution  is :

```
x1 = 2

x2 = 3

x3 = -1
```

Using Line 4, the output matrix is :

```
1   0   0    -0.75  
0   1   -0   8  
0   0   1    -1.5
```

and the solution is :

```
x1 = -0.75

x2 = 8

x3 = -1.5
```

Comment: Where's the declaration of `a`?  It's rather essential to having any of this code work.

Comment: Oops sorry! Forgot to mention it. It's a float array I declared in the class (not shown) as float a[50][50];

Comment: You will get better and faster response if you include all the relevant code so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Hey Neil. I'm new to Stack Overflow. Had some difficulties with formatting the code before. Included all of the code now! :)

Comment: For safety you should check if input `n` is greater than the array size or not. Or you could use `std::vector` to allow for any size. Vector or `std::array` would also perform bounds checking on good compilers which would help detect bugs.

Comment: If you were computing from source array `a` into a different result array it would work fine. Working "in place" on `a`, result values are writing over source values before they're used.  This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ByteMan2021 , please note that you have in line 71 a solution based on the extension of the compiler.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm I don't think I understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ByteMan2021, standard C++ does not support variable-length arrays,which are a gcc extension. Your code won't compile in clang or cl.

Comment: @Gene Realised my mistake! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Oh alright.

Comment: @NeilKirk Haven't used std::vector or std::array before. I'll try incorporating them in my programs henceforth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Line #4 reads from `a[j][i]` many times, and the first time through the inner loop, when `k == i`, changes `a[j][i]` to 0.0f, thus breaking the next `n-i` iterations.

Reordering reads of a variable with a write to the same location is not safe.

Comment: Ahh, that explains why the rest of the elements remained unchanged in the row echelon form.Thanks a lot!